# Changes to iptables has no effect. What's wrong with my script?

Tags: centos, iptables

This is my iptables script which i run in bash. The saving of the configurations is part of the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# iptables-konfigurasjon
#

# Set default rule to ACCEPT to avoid being locked out
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT

# Flush all excisting rules
 iptables -F

# New default rules
 iptables -P INPUT DROP
 iptables -P FORWARD DROP
 iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

# localhost:
 iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Not entirely shure what this is about....:
 iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow SSH.
 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Allow http traffic for tomcat:
 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT

# Save rules:
 /sbin/service iptables save
```

But, after testing it seems that these rules have no effect after all.
Example: If I comment out the line for allowing traffic to my tomcat server, I can still reach my tomcat server from outside.... even after a reboot.

What's wrong with my script?

BTW: I'm using CentOS 6.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

#### Why this happens

`iptables` functionalities are used by some other services like `ufw` or `firewalld` (depending on the distro you are using), which are blocking the changes made by `iptables` cli.

## Solution

All you have to do is just remove the package firewall pkg installed on your machine

for **ubuntu** (debian distros) using the following command to remove the package

```bash
sudo apt purge ufw -y
```

Answer (score 0):

after saving the newly added rules to your `iptables`, you have to restart the service so that changes take effect.

```
/sbin/service iptables restart
```

or

```
/etc/rc.d/init.d/iptables restart
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in the end of script (for the CentOS):

iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables

service iptables restart